# rosrun Error even when package compiles successfully

Tags: ros, package, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all! As seen from my previous posts, its been only about a month since I started using ROS. So pardon me if I am making any newbie error here.

I am trying to run a node on ros, but I am unable to do so. Here are the details:

package name: robot_node

ros version: ROS electric

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu Oneiric 32-bit

1. I opened a terminal and said

**roscore**

2. I went to the folder of the package and said rosmake

**roscd robot_node**

**rosmake**

This works perfectly fine. I am able to compile with 0 failures.

3. My executable is called 'robot_node.cpp' so I do the following

**rosrun robot_node robot_node**

And then, I get this 'error':

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named robot_node below ~/ros_workspace/ROS/robot_node
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   ~/ros_workspace/ROS/robot_node

There are a few things you should know that I already tried. These are

1. I checked the CMakeLists.txt for the package, and it does have the add_executable line.

2)I compiled all the first dependencies of the package separately, and they all compiled perfectly with 0 failures.

3. robot_node.cpp does have a **int main()** routine. :P

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36929/rosrun-error-even-when-package-compiles-successfully/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-06-20**:
Hey dornhege, here are your answers:
1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output of make obviously shows an error, that's why no binary file is generated. The problem probably is your call to ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND where you depend on another library. Did you check that the file `libABBInterpreter.a` really exists?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My suspicion is that you are not compiling the program at all or as you think you do.
So, answer the following questions:

- What is the output when you compile with rosmake and make?
- What is your CMakeLists.txt?
- Is there a binary robot_node in your package (possibly in bin/)?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1